# React props are concatenating when being passed down

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a fairly deep nested react component where I want to use a prop, to access the prop `movie` I have to traverse a nested mess:

```
const removeMovieFromDashboard = (movie) => {

  const removeMovieFromList = async (movie) => {
    const value = await localforage.getItem<any []>('trackedMovies');
    value.forEach((item, index) => {
      console.log(item.id === movie.movie.movie.movie.id)
      if (item.id === movie.movie.movie.movie.id) {
        value.splice(index, 1);
        localforage.setItem('trackedMovies', value)
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={() => removeMovieFromList(movie)}>Remove movie</div>
  )
}
```

As you can see I have to traverse 3 movie objects to get to the id `movie.movie.movie.movie.id`. I'm pretty sure React is smarter than that so I'm doing something wrong.

This is the structure I'm using:

`MovieOverview` receives a array of movies through the MovieContext and maps trough each movie create a child component:

```
let [movies, setMovies] = useContext(MovieContext)

return (
  <ul>
    { movies ? movies.map(movie => (
      <MovieOnDashboard movie={movie}/>
    )) : null}
  </ul>
)
```

The `MovieOnDashboard` accepts the prop passed down and renders a `OverlayEL` component which also accepts the prop.

```
const OverlayEl = (props) => {
  return (
    <Overlay>
      <RemoveMovieFromDashboard movie={props}/>
    </Overlay>
  )
}

const MovieOnDashboard = (movie) => {

  const imagePath = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/'
  const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MovieContainer 
      key={movie.movie.id}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}>
        <img src={imagePath + movie.movie.poster_path} alt='poster' />
      { isHover && <OverlayEl movie={movie} />}      
    </MovieContainer>
  )
}
```

The `OverlayEl` renders another component `RemoveMovieFromDashboard` that I've started the post with. So the `movie` prop gets passed down quite a few times.

Is there a way I don't keep stacking/concatenating props when I pass them down a component tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function component recieves a `props` object as argument and not a movie.

In `MovieOnDashboard` you are calling your props object (which will contain a key `movie`) `movie`. That's why you have to do stuff like `movie.movie`.

And when you call `<OverlayEl movie={movie} />`, `movie` will not be a movie, but a props object containing your movie. That's why your nested children have to do `movie.movie.movie...`.

You could rearange your code like this:

```
const MovieOnDashboard = ({ movie }) => { // we deconstruct the props to extract the movie

  const imagePath = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/'
  const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <MovieContainer 
      key={movie.id}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}>
        <img src={imagePath + movie.poster_path} alt='poster' />
      { isHover && <OverlayEl movie={movie} />}      
    </MovieContainer>
  )
}
```

Don't forget to update all your components.